# Jquery change css of parent

Tags: jquery, css, parent

I wanna change the style of the parent element by loading the site. I thought it would be possible like:

HTML

```
<p><script>setBGColor("True");</script>test</p>
```

JS

```
function setBGColor(status){
    if (status == "True")
        $(this.parent).css("background", "green");
}
```

But for some reason. It isn't getting green. Why not?

Comment: That's not going to work.  This is because of what the keyword `this` is referring to in the context of  your function.  the `this` keyword, when used within the context of a function, generally refers to the object that called the function.  Because you are calling within the script tag, it will refer to the window object (it's executing in the global context).  Thus, `this.parent` (or what should be `this.parentNode`) will be "undefined".  There might be a way to pull off what you're trying to do, but it's going to be messy and inadvisable.

Comment: Here's a little more info on [`this` in the global context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Global_context) (which is where your `this` is being evaluated)

Comment: Also, I think you want background-color.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/dehcs883/) You'll need to use some kind of selector to pick out the element you want in jQuery - in this example, it's `$("#test")` in line 4. `this` won't work like you're thinking it will in this example, like other users said.